# Can I upload the app bundle .aab file as an update of .apk (app signed APK) file?

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, signed-apk

*Hello All,*

*I have gone through the android blog and found that there is two ways for creating the APK file in android:*

**1. Android App Bundle (.aab)**

**2. Signed Apk (.apk).**

I have gone through the details and found that the size of both the files are different the .aab file size is low compare to .apk file.

Now my question is that my app is live and I use to upload the **.apk** file for the new update, So can I upload the **.aab** file this time as new update.

**will it work?**

Comment: Yes it will work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work with **.aab** file.

Comment: i uploaded aab earlier now can i upload apk instead of aab?

Comment: No most probably that won't be accepted there but still you can try :)

Comment: Does the existing apk need to be signed with the latest scheme (currently v4)? Or can the existing apk be on any signature scheme?

Comment: My guess is it can be of any version should take it. You can try. Please confirm if working or not over here as well. Thank you.